# How to add missing months to a column of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, na

I have a dataframe with a "month" column that has a number in it but I'm missing all the other months of the year because they have 0 data in it.
So I would like to have all the months of the year and put 0 to the months that have no data.

Here is an example of my data frame:

[image]

(I have a "yearmonth" column (2015 jui -2022 mai) & "month" column  & "year" column & an "n" column.)

Can you help me ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi isma, please take a look at the answer I posted below. If it solved your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept the solution, as this would be very helpful to others having the same issue. If this is not the case, feel free to use the comments to ask for futher details/clarification/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have set your locale to French (using `Sys.setlocale()`) this will output the completed dataframe, with the month-names in French, using `complete` from tidyverse:

```r
# copy of the data -----------------------
df <- structure(list(yearmonth = c("2015 jui", "2015 aoû", "2015 sep",
"2015 nov", "2015 déc", "2016 fév", "2016 mar", "2016 avr",
"2016 jul", "2016 aoû", "2016 oct", "2016 nov", "2017 fév",
"2017 jui", "2017 jul", "2017 aoû", "2017 nov", "2017 déc",
"2018 avr", "2018 mai", "2018 aoû", "2018 sep", "2019 jan",
"2019 fév", "2019 mar", "2019 jul", "2019 aoû", "2019 sep"),
month = c(6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 2, 6, 7,
8, 11, 12, 4, 5, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9), year = c(2015,
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016,
2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018,
2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), n = c(1, 2, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1,
1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")

# answer ----------------------------------
library(tidyverse)

df %>% complete(year = 2015:2019, month = 1:12, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste(year, month, "01", sep = "-")),
         yearmonth = format(date, format = "%Y %b")) %>%
  filter(between(date, as.Date("2015-06-01"), as.Date("2022-05-01"))) %>%
  select(-date)

#> # A tibble: 55 × 4
#>     year month yearmonth     n
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1  2015     6 2015 Jun      1
#>  2  2015     7 2015 Jul      0
#>  3  2015     8 2015 Aug      2
#>  4  2015     9 2015 Sep      1
#>  5  2015    10 2015 Oct      0
#>  6  2015    11 2015 Nov      1
#>  7  2015    12 2015 Dec      1
#>  8  2016     1 2016 Jan      0
#>  9  2016     2 2016 Feb      1
#> 10  2016     3 2016 Mar      1
#> # … with 45 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>